# How to install packages from Launchpad which are not in a PPA?

Tags: package-management, launchpad, install-from-source

Launchapad contains a wealth of packages that are not usable (they seem to be in source form or something).

For example, by searching for a "ndoc ubuntu" on google, I fell on the page https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ndoc which basically has no description, no documentation, no readme, no .deb, no nothing.

[image: Screenshot of part of the launchpad page]

Clicking on the "Code" tab shows different bzr branches for Trusty, Saucy, etc. but no .deb package. How can I get a .deb package for this software, or otherwise install it?

[image: Screenshot of the bzr branches]

This package is just an example, I frequently encounter such non-installable packages on Launchpad.

**Edit**: Is there a specific tool or configuration to use for launchpad packages that downloads, patches and builds everything including dependencies, or are we supposed to use the standard `bzr clone`, `./configure`, manually install all build dependencies, then `make`, `sudo make install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the package is no longer being built, due to either lack of updates upstream (the people who are developing `ndoc`) or compilation failures.

Note that the last commit in the [Trusty branch](https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/ndoc/trusty) was in 2009, back in the days of Jaunty and Karmic, which means this package didn't even enter Precise.

Also, note that [Debian doesn't have this package](http://packages.qa.debian.org/n/ndoc.html). In [this](http://packages.qa.debian.org/n/ndoc/news/20091105T032419Z.html) report, the reason for removal was "ROM; Old, abandoned upstream, terrible shape, crap, unused, should be burnt then salted then burnt again for good measure".

Comment: Thanks, do you have any pointers ho the procedure to use to build such a package (not this one obviously)? Is there a specific tool or configuration to use for launchpad packages that downloads, patches and builds everything including dependencies, or are we supposed to use the standard `bzr clone`, `./configure`, manually install all build dependencies, then `make`, `sudo make install`?

Comment: As a preface, with a package that was removed long ago, there's a good chance that a build dependency is not found (because of packages being renamed/split) or that the source is no longer compatible with the current versions of some libraries. To build the package (the Debian/Ubuntu way), you would have to do `bzr clone`, `cd` into the directory, and `debuild`. `debuild` will notify you of missing build dependencies, which you can use `apt-get` to install. If you don't have a GPG/PGP key (or if you don't know what this is), add `-us -uc` to the `debuild` command.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of your example you can't find because there are none

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/ndoc/1.3.1-6ubuntu1